# Jest with vanilla JS - tesing generated elements on DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jestjs

Searched a lot online but cant find the best way to get an element's innerHTML and just compare it with the results that should be rendered (I'm trying to compare with string)

```
expect(document.body.innerHTML.toString()).toBe("<div class='wrapper'><span>test</span></div>");
```

what I'm trying is adding some whitespace and test failed so I'm guessing there is better ways

Also, unable to query a specific element generated inside body, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Snapshot Testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing) to test the DOM tree structure.

> Snapshot tests are a very useful tool whenever you want to make sure your UI does not change unexpectedly.

E.g.

```
describe('67618056', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <span>test</span>
        </div>
    `;
    expect(document.body.innerHTML.toString()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      "
              <div class=\\"wrapper\\">
                  <span>test</span>
              </div>
          "
    `);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67618056/index.test.ts (7.563 s)
    ✓ should pass (17 ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        8.03 s, estimated 9 s
```

Comment: thanks. is there a better way for checking a really big div (with many inner divs)?

Comment: @MissPotato How do you want to check?

Comment: I've never used Jest like the OP before but I have the same question. Where does that `document` object come from? Who/what creates it?